# MySql and Entity Framework Core - MySqlException: Unknown column 's.CompanyId' in 'field list'

Tags: mysql, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core, google-cloud-sql

I am developing a ASP.NET Core frontend to connect to my Google Cloud SQL MySQL database.

I have the following model:

```cs
namespace shipping.Models
{
    public class ShippingAppContext : DbContext
    {
        public ShippingAppContext(DbContextOptions<ShippingAppContext> options) : base(options) { }

        public DbSet<Ship> ships { get; set; }
        public DbSet<Company> companies { get; set; }
    }

    public class Ship
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public virtual Company Company { get; set; }
    }

    public class Company
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public virtual ICollection<Ship> Ships { get; set; }
    }
}
```

and I iterate over `_context.ships.ToListAsync()` in a razor page which shows `ship.Name` and `ship.Company.Name`.

and my database is as follows:

```sql
MySQL [shipping]> show tables;
+--------------------+
| Tables_in_shipping |
+--------------------+
| companies          |
| ships              |
+--------------------+
MySQL [shipping]> select * from ships;
+------+-----------------+---------+
| Id   | Name            | Company |
+------+-----------------+---------+
|    1 | Eugen Maersk    |       1 |
|    2 | Madrid Maersk   |       1 |
|    3 | COSCO Vancouver |       4 |
|    4 | COSCO Rotterdam |       4 |
+------+-----------------+---------+
MySQL [shipping]> select * from companies;
+------+----------------------------------------------+
| Id   | Name                                         |
+------+----------------------------------------------+
|    1 | A.P. Moller–Maersk Group                     |
|    2 | Mediterranean Shipping Company S.A. (MSC)    |
|    3 | CMA CGM Group                                |
|    4 | China Ocean Shipping (Group) Company (COSCO) |
+------+----------------------------------------------+
```

This works fine with just show `ship.Name` but as soon as I try to show `ship.Company.Name` I get: `MySqlException: Unknown column 's.CompanyId' in 'field list'`.

I have done a search and `CompanyId` is not referenced anywhere in the project. The `ships` table does not contain a `CompanyId` column.

I guess this is probably because I have created the tables and data directly in the sql instance rather than using `dotnet ef` to create the database and upload it. But I don't think this is possible on Google Cloud SQL?

How can I make efcore do `INNER JOIN` from my model?

Answer (score 1):

If you are manually create the database , you can manually add the table schema with FOREIGN KEY constraints relationship(FK_ships_companies_CompanyId) ,so that you could query the related data like :

```
var result = _context.ships.Include(a=> a.Company).ToList();
```

Comment: Changed that and still getting `MySqlException: Unknown column 's.CompanyId' in 'field list'`